# jarInputStream.getManifest() is null

Tags: java, reflection, jar, reflections

When I upload a jar file to a servlet and try reading its manifest. jarStream.getManifest() returns null..

JarInputStream jarInputStream = new JarInputStream(inputStream);

**Manifest mf = jarInputStream.getManifest();**

While the same jar when I read as JarFile providing an absolute path, I get the manifest of the jar..

I need to read the manifest of the jar file at runtime..  when it is uploaded..

Any suggestions are most appreciated..

Comment: It's a bug or poorly documented feature of `JarInputStream`, see answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70363276/1795426 and also [JDK-8031748](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8031748)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By packaging the jar using ant script to provide the custom attributes to the manifest helped to get the manifest successfully.

previously I was packaging the jar using eclipse>export>java>java archive 
where the manifest was default, editing the manifest of this exported jar seemed to be the cause of the problem.

Thanks to @EJP and @Burkhard for quick responses to my query.

Comment: Same here. At first, I simply used zip and a custom made MANIFEST.MF. Creating the jar and manifest with ANT then worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

are you using java 1.4?
look at this [bug 4338238](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4338238)

Comment: More to the point, are you using an indexed JAR file? The bug is marked as 'unresolved', so the Java version doesn't come into it.

Comment: I am using eclipse juno to export the jar for my project , I am using jdk1.6.30 on 64 bit windows machine.. 
@EJP I haven't explicitly selected any configuration for generation of indexed JAR.