# JarInputStream retuns null for existing Manifest file

Tags: java, jar, manifest

I have a problem when using JarInputStream to get the Manifest of a (fully) operating .jar file, I get null pointer. Tried a few bit different files and no exception is thrown. Note : This file comes from a code generator. Has the following structure (hope this shape help you understand it):

```
|[+]test.jar
  |[+]META-INF
      |MANIFEST.MF
  |[+]mypackage
      |MyClass.class
|text.txt
```

Above is some part of the class (Note : This class is not located inside the .jar)

```
/*...code...**/
File jar = new File("resources/test.jar");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(jar);
JarInputStream jis = new JarInputStream(fis);
Manifest jarManifest = jis.getManifest();
Attributes jarManifestAttributes = jarManifest.getMainAttributes(); //line 25
String mainClass = jarManifestAttributes.getValue("Main-Class");
/*...code...**/
```

When running this code above, the below exception is throwed :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at crypter.LoadJar.main(LoadJar.java:25)
```

So jarManifest has null value.

**EDIT1**
MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: mypackage.MyClass
Permissions: all-permissions

Name: text.txt

Name: mypackage/MyClass.class
```

**EDIT2**

```
jar -tvf reverse_tcp2.jar 
    37 Sat Jan 07 11:31:14 EET 2017 text.txt
     0 Sat Jan 07 11:31:14 EET 2017 mypackage/
  8513 Sat Jan 07 11:31:14 EET 2017 mypackage/MyClass.class
     0 Sat Jan 07 11:31:14 EET 2017 META-INF/
   145 Sat Jan 07 11:31:14 EET 2017 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

Comment: Are you sure there is the resources folder at the folder the java is invoked?

Comment: @EnricoGiurin Yes, but if something like that happend FileNotFoundException should be thrown. I get none exception of this type

Comment: You are right, just tested

Comment: @EnricoGiurin I am posting the Manifest as well.

Comment: Yeah, it would be useful, just tried your code locally with a jar with a valid manifest, and it works

Comment: Very strange, I replaced the MANIFEST.MF with yours and it keeps working :(

Comment: @EnricoGiurin Thanks for your time. I'm gonna try solve it any way. Maybe it's something with the jvm or idk. Thanks for your time again!

Comment: @EnricoGiurin I fixed it by unzipping the jar and zipping it again without changing anything. I generated again the same jar from the generator and it didnt work. My experience cannot find a reason why this is happening.

Comment: Please post a listing of the content of the JAR file using `jar -tvf`. My guess is that the JAR file is being built with backslashes instead of forward slashes. What are those `Name:` entries for?

Comment: @EJP I did post it.

Comment: That's one answer to two questions.

Comment: @EJP I dont know what those name entries stand for. As I previous said the code come from a code generator

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4727637/how-do-i-verify-the-order-of-manifest-mf-within-jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug in [`JarInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarInputStream.html) that `MANIFEST.MF` must be in **the first entries** in a ZIP file, like this:

```
$ jar -tvf example-correct-archive.jar
  623 Thu Jun 13 12:13:42 CEST 2019 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
    0 Thu Jun 13 12:13:42 CEST 2019 META-INF/
    ...
```

In your case, you have 3 other files before that entries.

### Workarounds

a) Reorder entries in JAR file using `jar` tool:

- unpack `test.jar` file to directory `foo`
- move existing `MANIFEST.MF` file one level above directory `foo` and remove `META-INF` directory
- inside `foo` directory run command: `jar cvfm ../test.jar ../MANIFEST.MF .`
- outside of `foo` you will get fixed JAR file with correct entries order

b) use [`JarFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html) instead of `JarInputStream`

### More info

See [JDK-8031748 Clarify jar entry orders in a jar file](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8031748):

> From the beginning, the jar file has an “undocumented” assumption that
> the MANIFEST.MF file and signature-related files (block and SF) should
> appear at the beginning (except for directory entries, say,
> META-INF/).
> (...)